# Make ScrollController scroll bottom if already at bottom

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView.builder` with a `scrollController`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class StartProcessWidget extends HookWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  StartProcessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ouputs = useState<List<String>>([]);

    scrollDown() {
      if (scrollController.hasClients) {
        scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
      }
    }

    String generateRandomString(int len) {
      var r = Random();
      return String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(len, (index) => r.nextInt(33) + 89));
    }

    addElements() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ouputs.value = [...ouputs.value, generateRandomString(Random().nextInt(100))];
        sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      }
    }

    useEffect(() {
      addElements();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() {
      scrollDown();
    }, [ouputs.value]);

    return Container(
      height: 500,
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        itemCount: ouputs.value.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        prototypeItem: SelectableText(ouputs.value.first),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SelectableText(ouputs.value[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code scroll down to the bottom of the `ListView.builder` each time an element is added.

I want the `scrollController` to scroll down the `ListView` only if the user is already at the bottom of the `ListView` (like the chat on facebook for example).

I know that `scrollController.position.pixels` get the current position of the `ListView` and `scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` get the total height of the `ListView`. So if I could somehow find the last element height I could to something like:

```dart
scrollDown() {
  if (scrollController.hasClients &&
      scrollController.position.pixels + [lastElementHeight] == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
  ) {
    scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
  }
}
```

How can I dot that ?

Answer (score 0):

compare the `scrollController.position.pixels` with the `scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent`. If they are approximately equal (considering a small delta for floating point errors), it means the user is at the bottom

Example

```
scrollDown() {
  if (scrollController.hasClients) {
    double currentPosition = scrollController.position.pixels;
    double maxScrollExtent = scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;

    // Define a small delta to account for floating point errors
    double delta = 1.0;

    // Check if the user is at the bottom of the ListView
    if (currentPosition >= maxScrollExtent - delta) {
      scrollController.jumpTo(maxScrollExtent);
    }
  }
}
```

I did not try but it should work in theory

Comment: Hi, I could do like that the problem is I might have an `ouput` which can be very long so `scrollController.position.pixels` and `scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` won't be approximately equal. That why I need to know the last element height.